# Filtrar elementos de un array en php

Tags: php, laravel, array

mi duda es el cómo filtrar elementos de un array, en este caso quiero que se filtren las notas `>=` a 6, mi array es simple:

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
  2 => 4
  3 => 10
  4 => 7
  5 => 5
  6 => 10
]
```

Una vez filtrados me gustaría guardarlos en una variable, supongo que esta duda es super simple y básica. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas,

Te recomiendo siempre buscar en la documentación de PHP que está muy completa y traducida al español.

En este caso existe la función [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php)

A esta se le pueden pasar hasta tres argumentos

- El array a filtrar
- Un callback (una función que va a filtrar) **opcional**
- Un flag (esto se explica más a fondo en la documentación) **opcional**

Y devuelve un array con los elementos que pasaron el filtro

Para lo que vos requerís usaríamos `array_filter()`pasandole el array y el callback de la siguiente forma:

```
$nuevoArray = array_filter( 
    [
      0 => 1,
      1 => 2,
      2 => 4,
      3 => 10,
      4 => 7,
      5 => 5,
      6 => 10,
    ], 
    function ($elemento) {
        return $elemento >= 6;
    }
);
```

Ahora `$nuevoArray`tendría los elementos que tienen un valor `>=`a 6

Espero que esto te ayude y que me haya explicado bien, cualquier cosa decime que me intento explicar mejor o si no te respondí cambiar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, te explicaste perfecto.